# Apache NiFi - Using multiple FlowFiles as input to a processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a workflow where two or more inputs have set operations performed on them (union, complement, etc.) to produce a single output.  I expect to have to write a processor to do the set logic myself, but is it even possible to work with multiple flowfiles of different provenance and work on them simultaneously?

Comment: Can you describe how a sample set operation would work in concept (if not in NiFi)?  Most NiFi operations using multiple source flowfiles are of the merge, sort, or batch-put variety.

Comment: The most basic operation would be similar to a 'match and merge' (intersection) operation - take flowfiles A and B, and produce a single output flowfile with the elements common to A and B.  It sounds like merge/sort are getting close to what I want, though the docs for MergeContent seem to indicate it only supports one incoming connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NiFi processors can operate on all of the flowfiles in their input queue(s).  For example:

```
@Override
public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) {
    List<FlowFile> flowFiles = session.get(context.getProperty(BATCH_SIZE).asInteger());
    if (flowFiles == null || flowFiles.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    // process flowFiles
    ...
```

You can use the Funnel component to bring multiple inputs together into a single input queue, which can then share the same backpressure and prioritization settings.

[image: NiFi Funnel consolidating input queues]

Comment: This makes sense, but what if the arrival rate is very different (i.e. input A takes 1 minute to be generated, input B takes 10 minutes).  Is it possible to put input A "on hold" until you receive input B?

Comment: Some processors use an attribute to identify flowfiles as fragments of a whole.  If you knew that your data would have that pattern, you could skip flowfiles until the whole set arrived.